# I want to save dictionary while running same task again in Airflow

Tags: python, apache-spark, airflow

I have 30 Airflow tasks and in each task I am processing 3 classes at a time. For ex Task A has classes B, C and D. All the classes update the table. My issue is- let's say B got finished but C got failed and I reran the task. So, It will process class B again. But I want to maintain a dictionary for these classes and set class B to Y and persist this dictionary. If I want to re-run the same task, so it will start processing from class C. How we can do this without storying it in DB/file

Comment: Pickle the dictionary as you go. when you restart the task try to load the pickle. if it exists you can inspect it to see what things need to be rerun. Once you are done remove the pickle.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Pickle means to save the dictionary in a file? Which one is a better option to save in a file or in a table? Can't we use task instance or Xcomm(I know this could be used inter task but I am not sure whether we can use it if we are running same task again)